# toFixed not a function

Tags: javascript

Trying to display numbers on a calc but it says it isnt a function. I've used Number(variable.toFixed(x)) before but this time it doesnt seem to work inside of a document.getlementbyid. Any help?

```
    if (vi === 0){
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 
Number(reactant.toFixed(13));
} else if (vi >= 1 && tx === 0) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 
Number(reactant2.toFixed(13));
} else if (vi >= 1 && tx > 0) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 
Number(reactantspec.toFixed(13));
}
```

Comment: i guess reactant is a string then. if so convert to number before using toFixed()

Comment: What is `reactant`?

Comment: but when I use parseFloat to do that it treats 0.0 0.00 0.000 etc as a string anyway which means the calc doesnt render those numbers..

Comment: try using `toFixed` after you construct a number: `Number(reactant).toFixed(13)`

Comment: reactant is a string, a number that is used for the calculation in the calc

Comment: 5ar, my code is using toFixed right now..

Comment: copy all your code

Comment: there is 600+ lines, are you sure? and also how do you paste so much code, it always backs in to the left side of the text box and i have to press space on each of them.

Comment: First you convert to a number then call toFixed on it. Number(reactant).toFixed(13)

Comment: then copy the part where you put a value in reactantspec

Comment: @Benn CTRL + K formats code.

Comment: mwilson has already resolved your issue. It is the same thing I left you a comment for.

Comment: @Benn You're using `toFixed()` incorrectly. `toFixed` is a function on `Number.prototype`. `String.prototype` have no such function.

Comment: @sns works great but its now writing it as 0.000000000000 when reactant is equal to 0

Comment: anyone know how to stop it from displaying whole numbers that way

Comment: First you can check if (Number(reactant)) Number(reactant).toFixed(13)

This just means if reactant is not 0 (false) then we will call to fixed on it or else you should just use reactant as it will show as 0.

Comment: Or the other way around.

if (!Number(reactant)) { 
   return reactant;
} else { 
  return Number(reactant).toFixed(13);
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the example below.
Hope it helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the fixed number.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var reactant = '5.5678935436453256434';
    var n = Number(reactant).toFixed(13);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: works great, but still only thing is its writing out 0.0000000000000 instead of 0 first

Answer (score 3):

I am unsure of where `reactant` is coming from, but more than likely, it's a string value instead of a number.

```
"11.12123".toFixed(2); <-- toFixed is not a function error (becuase "11.12" is a string)

11.12123.toFixed(2); <-- Success!
```

You may need to convert your string to a number before running your `toFixed` logic:

```
Number("11.123").toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value from the element id i.e `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML` is a String, you should convert it to an integer using `parseInt()`

Comment: Your answer doesn't add any new information. Keep in mind that there are already two answers that state this.

Comment: I was on the verge of typing my answer and posting it while other answer popped in anyway.